# Cannot read property 't' of undefined using Vuetify and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

Getting this error when attempting to use a Vuetify component out of the box. Perhaps just my lack of understanding how to implement Vuetify components in Laravel.

Laravel v5.8.35, Vue v2.6.10, Vuetify v2.0.18.

error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of
>   undefined"
>
> found in
>
> ---> < VSelect >
>          < Test > at resources/js/components/Test.vue
>          < Root >

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.component('test', require('./components/Test.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

layouts/vue.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Vue Examples</title>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @yield("content")
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.vue')

@section('content')
    <test></test>
@endsection
```

components/Test.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row align="center">
      <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6">
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="Standard"
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>

      <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6">
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          filled
          label="Filled style"
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>

      <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6">
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="Outlined style"
          outlined
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>

      <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6">
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="Solo field"
          solo
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

As you can see, the vue file is exactly the source from Vuetify for the v-select component. Components that don't include this works:

```
  export default {
    data: () => ({
```

All other components (e.g. ExampleComponent) work fine.

Comment: You aren't creating a Vuetify instance. `new Vue({ el: '#app', vuetify: new Vuetify() })`. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object

Comment: I'm such a newb! Feel free to put your comment as an answer. Was a bit confusing since Laravel comes with Vue and Vuetify is an easy npm install.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to create an instance of Vuetify. e.g.:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify()
})
```

This is documented [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object), though they do hide it quite a long way down the page.

Comment: Thank you ! I had the same problem, your solution worked for me too, and I'm on Laravel 6 (mentioning for SEO purposes) ! Cheers !